# Web GIS App to analyse sub-national health and climate data

Tags: software-recommendations, climate, web-gis, health

the GIS app would have climate data of a district in raster format (extrapolated surfaces of weather station data for rainfall, temperature etc) and ACCEPT health data (e.g. geocoded malaria infections data for sampled health facilities in same district) over the same period and show the effects of climate patterns on the infections rate.....this app should enable anyone with geocoded data to do the same, so the climate rasters can be inbuilt no need of uploading each time

what is the best webGIS framework or approach i should go with here, if at all this application is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Geonode

**[GeoNode](http://geonode.org/)** combines WebGIS with social features. Anyone can upload, share and rate data as well as combine it with existing data. It also features [interactive mapping](http://geonode.org/user_features/#mapping). It [has been used](http://geonode.org/gallery/) in similar projects from organizations like e.g. the UN World Food Program.

> Supported upload formats include shapefile, GeoTIFF, KML and CSV. In addition, it is possible to connect to existing external spatial databases and services.

[image: GeoNode]

Comment: does geonode have the capability of doing a simple analysis to show, maybe, a pattern?

Comment: Styling single datasets and adding many datasets together for visualization YES. Analyzing by means of making calculations between independent datasets afaik NO.